# Why does Relay Modern send OPTIONS request

Tags: relayjs, relay, relaymodern

Is there a reason `relay modern` sends a `OPTIONS` request every so often?

While using pagination you can see multiple of these requests in the Network tab.

Comment: In its current form, your question isn't really about a programming problem. Could you edit your question and elaborate on why you want to know about this request, if the OPTIONS request is causing any problems, and what you have tried to so far to fix these problems?

Comment: Is it possible that these are CORS preflight requests? If so, they're not optional presuming well behaved browser.

Comment: @LarsKristensen it isnt a problem at all. I was curious as to why `relay modern` runs this `preflight`. Sometimes in life there are no problems - just curiosities.